# Kurento RTSP to webRTC

Tags: webrtc, media-player, rtsp, samsung-smart-tv, kurento

Im a developping a Samsung Smart TV app with Samsung's TOAST and Caph-angular. I am on Windows 10.

When I call our server, I get an RSRP url encoded with H264 but, on smart TVs, RSRP is not supported. Then I have to "transform" the RSRP url to some webRTC one (I know very little about all this so sorry if the terms are incorrect).

I searched here and there and found Kurento which seems to be able to answer my needs.

Before trying Kurento within my app, I wanted to test it on a few demos. 
I was able to test one2many example without any problem but I am having trouble running rtsp2webrtc demo.

I git cloned kms-windows and https://github.com/lulop-k/kurento-rtsp2webrtc and tried to run the demo but the player is not displaying anything.

1) I double-click kms-windows\bin\kurento-media-server

2) I launch http-server in kurento-rtsp2webrtc

3) I reach http://localhost:8080/, type my sample rtsp url (rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov) and click on "start"

No error seems to happen, see console logs:

```
Local icecandidate {"candidate":"candidate:4033732497 1 udp 2113937151 192.168.0.104 62879 typ host generation 0 ufrag tZFB network-cost 50","sdpMid":"audio","sdpMLineIndex":0}
Local icecandidate {"candidate":"candidate:4033732497 2 udp 2113937150 192.168.0.104 62881 typ host generation 0 ufrag tZFB network-cost 50","sdpMid":"audio","sdpMLineIndex":0}
Local icecandidate {"candidate":"candidate:4033732497 1 udp 2113937151 192.168.0.104 62883 typ host generation 0 ufrag tZFB network-cost 50","sdpMid":"video","sdpMLineIndex":1}
Local icecandidate {"candidate":"candidate:4033732497 2 udp 2113937150 192.168.0.104 62885 typ host generation 0 ufrag tZFB network-cost 50","sdpMid":"video","sdpMLineIndex":1}
PlayerEndpoint-->WebRtcEndpoint connection established
oniceconnectionstatechange -> checking
icegatheringstate -> gathering
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:1 1 UDP 2013266431 192.168.0.104 61810 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:1 1 UDP 2013266431 192.168.0.104 61810 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:2 1 TCP 1019216127 192.168.0.104 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:2 1 TCP 1019216127 192.168.0.104 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:3 1 TCP 1015021823 192.168.0.104 52180 typ host tcptype passive","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:3 1 TCP 1015021823 192.168.0.104 52180 typ host tcptype passive","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:4 1 UDP 2013266431 fe80::6403:eba1:c2a3:9605 61812 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:4 1 UDP 2013266431 fe80::6403:eba1:c2a3:9605 61812 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:5 1 TCP 1019217663 fe80::6403:eba1:c2a3:9605 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:5 1 TCP 1019217663 fe80::6403:eba1:c2a3:9605 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:6 1 TCP 1015023359 fe80::6403:eba1:c2a3:9605 52182 typ host tcptype passive","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:6 1 TCP 1015023359 fe80::6403:eba1:c2a3:9605 52182 typ host tcptype passive","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:7 1 UDP 2013266431 fe80::f99b:72cd:cb28:1424 61814 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:7 1 UDP 2013266431 fe80::f99b:72cd:cb28:1424 61814 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:8 1 TCP 1019217663 fe80::f99b:72cd:cb28:1424 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:8 1 TCP 1019217663 fe80::f99b:72cd:cb28:1424 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:9 1 TCP 1015023359 fe80::f99b:72cd:cb28:1424 52184 typ host tcptype passive","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:9 1 TCP 1015023359 fe80::f99b:72cd:cb28:1424 52184 typ host tcptype passive","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:10 1 UDP 2013266431 192.168.56.1 61816 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:10 1 UDP 2013266431 192.168.56.1 61816 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:11 1 TCP 1019216895 192.168.56.1 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:11 1 TCP 1019216895 192.168.56.1 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:12 1 TCP 1015022591 192.168.56.1 52186 typ host tcptype passive","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:12 1 TCP 1015022591 192.168.56.1 52186 typ host tcptype passive","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:1 2 UDP 2013266430 192.168.0.104 61811 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:1 2 UDP 2013266430 192.168.0.104 61811 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:2 2 TCP 1019216126 192.168.0.104 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:2 2 TCP 1019216126 192.168.0.104 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:3 2 TCP 1015021822 192.168.0.104 52181 typ host tcptype passive","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:3 2 TCP 1015021822 192.168.0.104 52181 typ host tcptype passive","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:4 2 UDP 2013266430 fe80::6403:eba1:c2a3:9605 61813 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:4 2 UDP 2013266430 fe80::6403:eba1:c2a3:9605 61813 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:5 2 TCP 1019217662 fe80::6403:eba1:c2a3:9605 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:5 2 TCP 1019217662 fe80::6403:eba1:c2a3:9605 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:6 2 TCP 1015023358 fe80::6403:eba1:c2a3:9605 52183 typ host tcptype passive","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:6 2 TCP 1015023358 fe80::6403:eba1:c2a3:9605 52183 typ host tcptype passive","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:7 2 UDP 2013266430 fe80::f99b:72cd:cb28:1424 61815 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:7 2 UDP 2013266430 fe80::f99b:72cd:cb28:1424 61815 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:8 2 TCP 1019217662 fe80::f99b:72cd:cb28:1424 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:8 2 TCP 1019217662 fe80::f99b:72cd:cb28:1424 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:9 2 TCP 1015023358 fe80::f99b:72cd:cb28:1424 52185 typ host tcptype passive","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:9 2 TCP 1015023358 fe80::f99b:72cd:cb28:1424 52185 typ host tcptype passive","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:10 2 UDP 2013266430 192.168.56.1 61817 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:10 2 UDP 2013266430 192.168.56.1 61817 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:11 2 TCP 1019216894 192.168.56.1 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:11 2 TCP 1019216894 192.168.56.1 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:12 2 TCP 1015022590 192.168.56.1 52187 typ host tcptype passive","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"}
Remote icecandidate {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:12 2 TCP 1015022590 192.168.56.1 52187 typ host tcptype passive","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"}
Player playing ...
oniceconnectionstatechange -> connected
icegatheringstate -> complete
oniceconnectionstatechange -> completed
icegatheringstate -> complete
```

But the player does not display anything. I still see the spinner.

I tried adding a STUN server (not sure what it is or if I even need one, just saw this in docs or other stackoverflow issues) and it did not solve anything.

Could you please help me?
Did I do anything wrong or forget something?
And, in the future, when I want to implement this into my tv web app, will I only need to include kurento-client.js and kurento-utils.js files or will there be other things to take care of?

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you Kurento server is behind the NAT - you need to use TURN server for it.

Comment: That was the solution, thanks!

Comment: if I help you, set my answer as resolved. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stun server cannot traverse symmetric NAT's so for that purpose if your server is behind NAT then you should try using TURN server

Comment: Hello Alicia, I am facing same issue. When I start get these messages - 

Player playing ...
oniceconnectionstatechange -> failed
icegatheringstate -> complete

So, oniceconnectionstatechange is getting failed.

Answer (score 1):

if you Kurento server is behind the NAT - you need to use TURN server for it